# Short story where a human kills an alien sent to test humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I remember the basic plot of it. A family encounters an extraterrestrial being in need of help but the father of the family is afraid of it and ends up shooting it. The being was sent as a test for humans to see if they could be trusted. The aliens say they have lost their chance to live forever amongst the stars.

I read in high school around 2013 if that helps.

Comment: This sounds familiar, but there's so few details to work with. Can you remember anything else about the story? Was it a short story or was it long like a novel? Was the perspective from the alien or the humans? What approx. period in history or the future was this set?

Answer (score 2):

This description reminds me a little of "The Replicators" (1965), a short story by A E van Vogt. The protagonist keeps killing the alien, which returns with larger versions of the tools/weapons that were used to kill it.